# How to print fibonacci number, multithreading?

Tags: java

The task is to write a program that creates and starts two threads ThreadFibonacci and ThreadOutput. ThreadFiobnacci should calculate the fibonacci numbers and put the results in its static public variable. ThreadOutput should output the fibonacci number and ThreadOutput has to be a daemon thread. You have to make the thread write out each fibonacci number only once. I do not know how to do that last part of the task.

You can only use sleep, interrupt, volatile and join.

Here is what I tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zadatak2{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int n = reader.nextInt();

    Thread threadFibonaci = new Thread(new ThreadFibonaci(n));
    Thread threadOutput = new ThreadOutput();

    threadFibonaci.start();
    threadOutput.start();

  }
}

class ThreadFibonaci implements Runnable{

  public static volatile long fn;
  private int n;

  public ThreadFibonaci(int n){
    this.n = n;
  }

  public void run(){
    long f0 = 0;
    fn = f0;
    try{
      Thread.sleep(500);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long f1 = 1;
    fn = f1;
    try{
      Thread.sleep(500);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      fn = f0 + f1;
      f0 = f1;
      f1 = fn;
      try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}

class ThreadOutput extends Thread{

  public ThreadOutput(){
    setDaemon(true);
  }

  public void run(){
    while(true){
      System.out.println(ThreadFibonaci.fn);
      try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Look up "producer and consumer" for similar questions

Comment: Can you use a BlockingQueue? You need to say what you can't use as there is plenty of obvious ways to do this I assume your homework doesn't allow.

Comment: You can only use sleep, interrupt, volatile and join.

Comment: That is vital to include in the question. Btw volatile alone is enough, do you have to use the others?

Comment: I think `sleep` is needed because volatile int/long can store only one current number and calculating thread needs to wait while printing thread prints it before overwriting with next number @PeterLawrey

Comment: i don't believe this can be done  since you have no control with threads how should start 
if you do use any of Thread Safe components (Classes) then you lost the power of thread and it will be executed just like non thread, it will be wasting resource only

Comment: @Ivan I have added an example without sleep.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi the answer I gave wastes resources but works. ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that good luck i will check the solution
Please if someone helped you mark it as accepted answer to help other people that who may face same problem

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Ivan's answer also works and might be closer to what was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need top use one more `volatile` variable to store a flag whether current number was already printed or not

```
class ThreadFibonaci implements Runnable{

  public static volatile long fn;
  public static volatile boolean printed = false;
  private int n;

  public ThreadFibonaci(int n){
    this.n = n;
  }

  public void run(){
    long f0 = 0;
    fn = f0;
    while (!printed) {
      try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    long f1 = 1;
    fn = f1;
    printed = false;
    while (!printed) {
      try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
      fn = f0 + f1;
      f0 = f1;
      f1 = fn;
      printed = false;
      while (!printed) {
        try{
          Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
 }
}

class ThreadOutput extends Thread{

 public ThreadOutput(){
   setDaemon(true);
 }

 public void run(){
   while(true){
     while (ThreadFibonaci.printed) {
       try{
         Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     System.out.println(ThreadFibonaci.fn);
     ThreadFibonaci.printed = true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think it was expected that sleep is used though it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a single `volatile` field to hold the value. when the value is `0` a new value can be published and when the value is negative, it acts as a poison pill, stopping the printing thread.

```
class A {
    static volatile long value = 0;
    static void publish(long x) {
        while (value > 0) ;
        value = x;
    }
    static long next() {
        while (value == 0) ;
        long ret = value;
        if (ret > 0) value = 0;
        return ret;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        new Thread(() -> {
            long a = 1; publish(a);
            long b = 1; publish(b);
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                long c = a + b; publish(c);
                a = b; b = c;
            }
            publish(-1); // poison pill
        }).start();
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (; ; ) {
                long value = next();
                if (value < 0) break;
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without `sleep` this is pure spin waiting. Printing thread is a daemon. You do not even need to stop it to exit JVM

Comment: @Ivan spin waiting is a common technique when there is a tight interaction between threads.